# SVG dynamic width and height from html or css

Tags: html, css, svg

I want give my SVG element dynamic width and height and want to show full my SVG image.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWqRxp?editors=1010

```
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
```

or

```
.svg {
  width : 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

I want to show full map in 250x250 box.

I tried everything for this but ....

Comment: Is this what you look for: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJVxXY

Answer (score 1):

Your viewBox is wrong. `"0 0 250 250"` is not a suitable value for your SVG.

More suitable values for your SVG would be something like: `"0 398 612 394"`.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpeVNW?editors=1010